# Partial page rendering with Primefaces - JSF 2.0 navigation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, facelets, primefaces

I am trying to create a facelet page which updates `<ui:insert>` elements with ajax calls. Whenever a `<p:commandButton action="next"/>` is clicked ajax call should take place and only `<ui:insert>` parts of the facelet template should be updated. My question is exactly same as the question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685354/partial-page-update-when-navigating-primefaces-ajax) but the solution over there does not work. Furthermore, considering the comment, it is quite ambiguous if the answer is accepted or not. I am stuck without any solution and not sure if this is related to [PrimeFaces FAQ#4](http://www.primefaces.org/faq.html)

I have another solution proposal with `<ui:import>` but not quite sure if this is a good solution. I am storing active page in a bean attribute and updating the value with ajax calls. So any comments and/or ideas are more than appreciated.
Here is my proposal:

#### template.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
<title><ui:insert name="title" />
</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">Primafaces Partial Page Update navigation</div>

    <h:panelGroup id="content" layout="block">
        <ui:insert name="content">
                Sample content.
            </ui:insert>
    </h:panelGroup>
</div>

<div id="footer">Made using JSF &amp; Primefaces</div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

#### main.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui" template="template.xhtml">

<ui:define name="title">Main page</ui:define>

<ui:define name="content">
    <ui:include src="#{navBean.activePage}" />
</ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

#### NavigationBean.java

```
@Component("navBean")
@Scope("session")
public class NavigationBean implements Serializable{
private String activePage="firstAjax.xhtml";
public String getActivePage() {
    return activePage;
}
public void setActivePage(String activePage) {
    this.activePage = activePage;
}
public void next(ActionEvent e) {
    this.setActivePage("lastAjax.xhtml");
}
public void back(ActionEvent e) {
    this.setActivePage("firstAjax.xhtml");
}
}
```

#### firstAjax.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">

<h2>First Page!</h2>
<h:form>
    <p>Click the button to go to next page!</p>
    <p:commandButton value="Next"
        actionListener="#{navBean.next}" update=":content" />
</h:form>

</ui:composition>
```

#### lastAjax.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">

<h2>Last Page!</h2>
<h:form>
    <p>Click the Back button to go to previous page!</p>
    <p:commandButton value="Back"
        actionListener="#{navBean.back}" update=":content" />
</h:form>

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: I use the may you described and it works well.

Comment: Did you find a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

Up to now I had the same problem you mention and your post gave me the clue to resolve it. I intended to do exactly what you're trying to do so I hope my solution can help you.

My index page, that contains the menu and the container in which the content is updated:

```
<ui:composition template="./../resources/templates/template.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="menu">
                    <ui:include src="./../resources/templates/menu.xhtml"/>
                </h:panelGroup>

                <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="content">
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="content" rendered="#{menuBacking.albums}">
                        <ui:include src="albums.xhtml"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>   
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="content" rendered="#{menuBacking.band}">
                        <ui:include src="band.xhtml"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>   
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="content" rendered="#{menuBacking.concerts}">
                        <ui:include src="concerts.xhtml"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>   
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="content" rendered="#{menuBacking.contacts}">
                        <ui:include src="contacts.xhtml"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>  
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>
```

The menu included in the first panelGroup:

```
<p:menu>
    <p:menuitem value="Albums" action="#{menuBacking.active}" update="content">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="albums" target="#{menuBacking.selection}"/>
    </p:menuitem>
    <p:menuitem value="Band" action="#{menuBacking.active}" update="content">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="band" target="#{menuBacking.selection}"/>
    </p:menuitem>
    <p:menuitem  value="Concerts" action="#{menuBacking.active}" update="content">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="concerts" target="#{menuBacking.selection}"/>
    </p:menuitem>
    <p:menuitem value="Contacts" action="#{menuBacking.active}" update="content">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="contacts" target="#{menuBacking.selection}"/>
    </p:menuitem>
</p:menu>
```

This is one of the pages I want to display into the content area (just for test purpose):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<body>
    Contacts
</body>
```

And finally, the bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MenuBacking implements Serializable {
    private String selection;
    private boolean albums;
    private boolean band;
    private boolean concerts;
    private boolean contacts;

    public MenuBacking() {
       albums = false;
       band = true; // You can define the default page that will be show
       concerts = false;
       contacts = false;
    }

    // getters & setters

    public void active() throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
       setAlbums(selection.equals("albums"));
       setBand(selection.equals("band"));
       setConcerts(selection.equals("concerts"));
       setContacts(selection.equals("contacts"));
    }
}
```

Be aware the difference between  action and actionListener. Action first assigns the value to the property and then execute the method, while actionListener execute the method and then assigns the value.

Comment: Actually I am looking for a solution that does not require saving the page state in a backing bean. Normally facelet templating just works when `action="destination"`matches `destination.xhtml` but it is a full page request. I am looking for the same mechanism with Partial Rage Rendering (PPR) and ajax. Do I miss something? Is it technically impossible? Maybe I do not have a clear understanding of templating and PPR. The main reason I want that is I want to use primefaces (jsf) in a portlet and do not want to make full page request while still being able to use templating.

Answer (score 1):

I made this by using a view path from a bean for including it directly. This is very simple:

```
<ui:composition
    template="/WEB-INF/includes/templates/page-template.jspx"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">

<ui:define name="page-content">
    <ui:include src="#{navigation.selectedIncludePath}" />
</ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Then, everytime when the property 'selectedIncludePath' on my navigation bean changes (triggered by ActionEventListeners), the view part named 'page-content' gets updated.

To be clear, the string property 'selectedIncludePath' is filled with filenames to xhtml files.

```
selectedIncludePath = "/WEB-INF/includes/info/about.xhtml";
```

Of course, this can be updated throu EL from inside a view as well.